# Altering JSON Structure

Tags: json

So I am using a webscraper to pull information on sneakers from a website. The son data that comes back is structured like so

```
[
  {
    "web-scraper-order": "1554084909-97",
    "web-scraper-start-url": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers",
    "productlink": "$200AIR JORDAN 6 RETRO 'INFRARED' 2019",
    "productlink-href": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers/air-jordan-6-retro-black-infrared-384664-060",
    "name": "Air Jordan 6 Retro 'Infrared' 2019",
    "price": "Buy New - $200",
    "description": "The 2019 edition of the Air Jordan 6 Retro ‘Infrared’ is true to the original colorway, which Michael Jordan wore when he captured his first NBA title. Dressed primarily in black nubuck with a reflective 3M layer underneath, the mid-top features Infrared accents on the midsole, heel tab and lace lock. Nike Air branding adorns the heel and sockliner, an OG detail last seen on the 2000 retro.",
    "releasedate": "2019-02-16",
    "colorway": "Black/Infrared 23-Black",
    "brand": "Air Jordan",
    "designer": "Tinker Hatfield",
    "technology": "Air",
    "maincolor": "Black",
    "silhouette": "Air Jordan 6",
    "nickname": "Infrared",
    "category": "lifestyle",
    "image-src": "https://image.goat.com/crop/1250/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/018/675/318/original/464372_01.jpg.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "web-scraper-order": "1554084922-147",
    "web-scraper-start-url": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers",
    "productlink": "$190YEEZY BOOST 350 V2 'CREAM WHITE / TRIPLE WHITE'",
    "productlink-href": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers/yeezy-boost-350-v2-cream-white-cp9366",
    "name": "Yeezy Boost 350 V2 'Cream White / Triple White'",
    "price": "Buy New - $220",
    "description": "First released on April 29, 2017, the Yeezy Boost 350 V2 ‘Cream White’ combines a cream Primeknit upper with tonal cream SPLY 350 branding, and a translucent white midsole housing full-length Boost. Released again in October 2018, this retro helped fulfill Kanye West’s oft-repeated ‘YEEZYs for everyone’ Twitter mantra, as adidas organized the biggest drop in Yeezy history by promising pre-sale to anyone who signed up on the website. Similar to the first release, the ‘Triple White’ 2018 model features a Primeknit upper, a Boost midsole and custom adidas and Yeezy co-branding on the insole.",
    "releasedate": "2017-04-29",
    "colorway": "Cream White/Cream White/Core White",
    "brand": "adidas",
    "designer": "Kanye West",
    "technology": "Boost",
    "maincolor": "White",
    "silhouette": "Yeezy Boost 350",
    "nickname": "Cream White / Triple White",
    "category": "lifestyle",
    "image-src": "https://image.goat.com/crop/1250/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/014/822/695/original/116662_03.jpg.jpeg"
  },
```

However, I want to change it so that the top level node is sneakers and the next level down would be a specific sneaker brand ( Jordan, Nike, Adidas) and then the list of sneakers that belong to that brand. So my JSON structure would look something like this

```
Sneakers {
Adidas :{
[shoe1,
 shoe2,
 ....

] },
Jordan: {
[shoe1,
 shoe2,
 ....

]
}
}
```

I am not sure what tool I could use to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. All I have at the moment is the JSON file and it is not in the structure that I want it to be in.

Comment: why did I get a downvote

Comment: Probably because your question doesn't contain any attempts to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to populate a dict whose keys are brand names and their values are lists of sneaker records. Assuming that `data` is your original list, here's the code:

```
sneakers_by_brand = {}

for record in data:
    if sneakers_by_brand.get(record.get("brand")):
        sneakers_by_brand[record.get("brand")].append(record)
    else:
        sneakers_by_brand[record.get("brand")] = [record]

print(sneakers_by_brand)
```